# Linkhandler in editor of extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

Using the linkhandler function of TYPO3 > 8 works fine for content ckeditor elements. But how do I get those additional link browser tabs in rich text fields in news or any other extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have added the new linkhandler-type with TSConfig right? Then this new wizard should be available in all link wizards of every subpage of the page containing your TSconfig. Maybe your News are located inside a folder outside of the TSconfig affected pages?